# How can I draw a table with vertical lines not aligned in Latex

Tags: latex, tabular, multicol

I want to draw a table like that but don't know how to
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAu85.png)

I tried multirow and multicol but it doesn't work, or i don't know to use it correctly :<<< i find no one who had problem like me. Help mee

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with the juxtaposition of two tabulars.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\offinterlineskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
Cell 1 & Cell 2 \\
\end{tabularx} \newline
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
Cell 3 & Cell 4 & Cell 5 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]